# Blinking cursor when installing latest Ubuntu 32 bit

Tags: software-installation

I there.

I am trying to install Ubuntu 32 bit on my PC.

I get to the screen where you can choose to install on its own or along side windows.

I chose clean install, then just get a blinking underscore.

Can anybody assist with this please?

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to install Ubuntu CD or USB?. Try formatting the USB and re-installing the latest ubuntu bootable USB or CD installer. Also rather that install on its own try and see if whatever medium you are using will let you "try ubuntu" - once that goes through you will still have the option to install when you are using the live version of the "demo ubuntu".